# Mac Apache Instance Loads "It Work" Page fine, but It Does Not Load Directories or Any Other File

Tags: macos, apache, terminal, localhost, server

I must have gone a little nuts over the last couple of days. I'm pretty familiar with Apache(moderately seasoned developer under Linux and Windows environments), but my Mac(company equipment; not actually mine machine) Apache instance will not load any page other than the "It Works" page. (found at /Library/WebServer/Documents)

I will not show any configuration because I literally just started it with any of the following commands: sudo apachectl start/stop/restart (I condensed it for brevity). Created a few virtual hosts. Added a one liner host to the hosts file, for easy access. That's it. The rest of the settings are defaults. Also, I would like to point out that 127.0.0.1 does not work as well. Localhost is the only "host" name that works. In the sharing section under settings, the sharing "web server" option is not present.(this is a rather new Mac. It is not Yosemite OS though).

I use "brew" as my package manager.

Answer (score 0):

/Library/webserver/documents does not sound like the default www root to me. Are you putting your pages in the right folder?

You would need to check the apache conf file for the  tags and you should see the folder where the pages are stored.

Comment: This is a Mac. Mac is a very strange creature. The "www" documentRoot directory (commonly found in linux machines) is not present. At least for this operating system. I have researched this topic online too because it confused me at first. However, it all indicates that /Library/WebServer/Documents is the DocumentRoot (directory). I looked in the httpd.conf file, and settings pointed to the aforementioned directory. I'm not using the MAMP stack. I searched for the www directory in my system, and it does not exist as well.

Comment: What exactly do you see when you try to access another page? 404?

Comment: Page/directory "Cannot be found". It does not even list directory's content. It's very strange.